# Modify an xml files in a jar file with Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jar

I currently am tasked with updating an XML file (persistance.xml) within a jar at a customers site.  I can of course unjar the file, update the xml, then rejar the file for redeployment.  I would like to kind these command line operations in a Swing App so that the person doing it does not have to drop to the command line.  Any thoughts on a way to do this programatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Java API has [classes](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html) for manipulating JAR files.

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

```
File tmp = new File ("tmp");
tmp.mkdirs();
Process unjar = new ProcessBuilder ("jar", "-xf", "myjar.jar", tmp.getName ()).start();
unjar.waitFor();
// TODO read and update persistence.xml
Process jar = new ProcessBuilder ("jar", "-cf", "myjar.jar", tmp.getName()).start();
jar.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java's [ZipFile](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) and [ZipEntry](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html) classes to read the contents of a JAR file, then use [ZipOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) to create a new one.